# Main activity to second activity and from second activity to main activity by button

Tags: android, button, webview

Main activity to second activity and from second activity to main activity by button.

I have tried this code but when I click on the button it's not going to the main activity , I tried all option but it's not working .

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webview;
    private Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                        final String failingUrl) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

                super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);


            }

        });
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new handleButton());
    }

    class handleButton implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="ram.idea.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HOME"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN2.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ram.idea.Main2Activity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="82dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Error:
[image]

Android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ram.idea">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you do not enter the Activity2Main, you only set the view. Try:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                final String failingUrl) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
       startActivity(intent);

        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);


    }

});
```

In your MainActivity.
And you could add:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

     (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The complete MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webview;
private Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                    final String failingUrl) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);// Try this
            startActivity(intent); //Try this
        }
    });
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        }
    });
}

}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

[this happen when i added your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs0iy.jpg)

Comment: Why do you use an extra class?

Comment: thanks for your response but (new handleButton()) its shows error what i should add

Comment: You could simply use View.OnClickListener(). there is no difference in your case

Comment: look at my second piece of code. It is for the second Activity

Comment: You should write classes in Uppercase

Comment: im trying but exactly where i should  paste

Comment: how du you enter your second Activity?

Comment: yeah i have added but when i click button its not going to mainactivity

Comment: by this  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description,
                                    final String failingUrl) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);


        }

Comment: you are in mainactivity but the layout was the one form the secondActivity

Comment: no you only set the contentView. You are still in the main Activty. look at my code!

Comment: Okay.. no problem... You can only acces an activity using Intent. You tried to access an activity using setContentVIew, but this only changes the layout which is shown not the activity. So, you had to change/ add the onReceivedError method. This is my second code snippet. This helps you to get to the second Activity. And your secondActivity should work absolutley fine :)

Comment: but when i added code but its changed i have attached image please check out and give solution

Comment: what change i should do

Comment: the onError metohd

Comment: men... you can simply change the onError method of your Webview. The code for this is in my awnser! You should only add the Intent thing to tihs

Comment: should I add this to your question so you could paste it?

Comment: but the problem is when no internet web page not available error is coming

Comment: web page not available when i click home on button or when no internet

Comment: What has this to do with the question? Post your LogCat... but your question is about Intents.

Comment: where is the problem now ? And what looks your current code like

Comment: the only change I do was to actually start the activity. There is no change in functionality

Comment: you could try to remove this 'super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);'

Comment: could you explain it a bit more detailed where your problem accours? and could you update your awnser code with the improvement we made?

Comment: I have added an full awnser with the whole MAninActivity code

Comment: ok thanks so much for ur help once i check i will let you know

Answer (score 0):

try to use :
finish(); method after the startActivity(intent);